# Prevent User From Spamming - Jquery Append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spam

How can I prevent a user from spamming? Like, how to prevent a user if he enters comments rapidly and quickly, again and again?

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jE9p/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<p>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_more">Add More</a>
</p>

<table border="0" width="500" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody class="append_data"></tbody>

  <tr>
    <td> 
      <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
    </td> 
  </tr> 

</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#description{
  width:400px;    
}

.description_text{
  border:#333333 solid 1px;
  width:400px !important;
}

.append_data{
  white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
  white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
  word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.add_more').click(function(){
    var description = $('#description').val();
    $(".append_data").append('<div class="description_text">'+description+'</div><br><br>');
  });
```

Comment: _"How can i prevent User from Spamming?"_ In the long run you can't.

Comment: But anyway to control or Handle it ?

Comment: the data doesn't go anywhere, they can only spam themselves, and that's boring...

Comment: @dandavis The Data is going to Database using Ajax on each comment.

Comment: Nothing in JavaScript will work, because javascript can be cheated (it runs clientside). You need to add spam controls to your server code.

Comment: oh, then they can still spam by turning off javascript....

Comment: @dandavis If they turn off javascript then nothing will get posted.  How do they spam if nothing gets posted?

Comment: Just because the page's javascript is disabled, doesn't mean they can't hit your posting API repeatedly. Controls like this *need* to be server-side, and *can* be client side as well to promote UX

Comment: @archer: ajax is not the only way to hit urls, and it's not even the way spammers send spam. if the server doesn't reject spam, nothing javascript does will help all but the most pathetic attempts.

Comment: They don't have to use a browser. Spambots don't ;) All anti-spam stuff must be done on the server, otherwise it can be bypassed.

Comment: anecdotally, i have had luck simply setting the form action attrib with javascript. seems spammers don't know how to fire js yet. no phantom.js yet guys? anyway, we saw about a 90% drop in spam after making the tiny switch, even if it leaves a few legit users w/o JS SOL.

Comment: Just need to handle it using Jquery

Comment: @dandavis I was talking about this question, so what I said was correct.  If you're talking about people "hacking" the page contents then there's very little that can be done.

Comment: Any secondary solution will work. Which would be close to prevent from rapid comments / spam

Answer (score 0):

U can try adding + 1 to variable everytime someone clicks add button, and setInterval that will make variable = 0 every n seconds

Comment: Super-easy to work around for a spammer: send the POST requests by some other means. Nothing client-side can stop spam, hacks or bad data in general.

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

http://jsfiddle.net/7jE9p/2/

I've made it hide the "add more" link for 10 seconds when you click it...

```
$('.add_more').click(function() {
    var description = $('#description').val();
    $(".append_data").append('<div class="description_text">'+description+'</div><br><br>');
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.show();
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Well thats not what I am looking for. Plus its annoying for a user. I used append for fast response.

Comment: You need to be clear about what you want then as that 100% gives you what you asked for.  It stops the user being able to rapidly enter more responses.

Comment: All I want is to stop User from entering too many comments at the same time. Because its append and its works too fast. And thats what i wanted to build. Like facebook comments are working too fast. You cant even spam there

Comment: Sorry, but in that case I have absolutely no idea what you're asking.  The above code does exactly what you asked.  It stops "user from entering too many comments at the same time".

Comment: Well i really appreciate your help, but thats just a delay. And delay is not a solution here. I would like your to check FACEBOOK. Just Go and starting Clicking Rapidly on "Like" button. keep doing it for a Minuit.You will get to my point. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used a sessionStorage variable and set an interval. This makes it so that you can't click on the add more button for 60 seconds after adding content

http://jsfiddle.net/vMcEE/

```
`sessionStorage.timer = 0;
  setInterval(function(){if (sessionStorage.timer > 0) {sessionStorage.timer--}},1000);
  $('.add_more').click(function(){
                         if (sessionStorage.timer == 0){
                             sessionStorage.timer += 30
                        var description = $('#description').val();
                        $(".append_data").append('<div class="description_text">'+description+'</div><br><br>');
                         }
                         });`
```

Comment: What if I bypass your javascript and post directly to the URL from a script that sends dozens of requests per second?

Comment: @ECWyne  Well thats not what I am looking for. Plus its annoying for a user.

Answer (score 0):

If it's humans putting in spam comments, then use functions like set-timeout or use a plugin like [jQuery Debounce](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/), set to 60 seconds, and let people get frustrated.

Hypothetically, if you're just doing 'rate limiting' as opposed to spammed comments, then the above solution would be okay (helpful for 'chat room' like behaviour and such) to prevent people from going like

a

b

c

d

e

post...

It's still not as strong as using server side, but it can get you about halfway there.

But if it's spambots, you could use a few different techniques, that the set-timeout won't do (because they can hammer at your site for 24hr/day without a problem). First is, as a few people pointed out, server side validation. They make an AJAX request, your service responds, you check against their profile, and use a last time posted variable, check that against current time. If current time - last posted < interval, return a message that you can handle with jQuery.ajax a la

```
.done(function(data) {
  if(data.timeoutCode == 1) {
    $.append("You can't post again so quickly");
  }})
```

You could also use a fantastically old hacky technique of adding an extra field that spambots usually will fill in... like

```
<input type="text" name="location" style="display:none"></input>
```

and spambots are blind, they'll fill in all fields, thinking that they'll get at server response back that it failed. but, on the javascript side, when you go to submit, check on your onclick button if $("input[name='location']).val().length > 0... if the length is greater than 0, it'll ignore the request (and save you a bit of effort on the server side as well), regular users won't touch it, because the field will be hidden and won't have the ability to fill it in. But that's something if they're just using the POST function available, the client side validation would still fail, and then you'd have to back it up with server side validation as well.

There really are no foolproof solution to providing a client-side spam solution... You can help on the client side.

Edit: Archer brought up a decent point.

I mean, the usecase is also weird, but, you could use event.which, before the post was made, to determine if the user clicked on the button (or used enter, or whatever), and only if they did it, then you could only show, to that particular user making the comment, that they did indeed press/click the submit and not use automation to make a submission. But then that brings up the weird usecase as to: if you're using jQuery.append, you're only impacting the current session's view, unless it's being routed through the server, and if it's being routed through the server, you should just check it on the server side...

Comment: There's also the "is human" check - `if (event.which) { triggered by a user } else { triggered by code }`